# How to post message on slack channel with a bot?

Tags: node.js, api, message, slack, slack-api

I try to params my bot like if someone on the channel says 'hello' my bot answer 'Que puis-je pour toi?'
To do this i have this :

```
const bot = new App ({
  token : process.env.SLACK_ACCESS_TOKEN,
  signingSecret: process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET,
  socketMode : true,
  appToken : process.env.SOCKET_TOKEN,
});

const web = new WebClient(process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,{logLevel: LogLevel.DEBUG});

(async () => {
await bot.start(process.env.PORT || 3000)
.catch(console.error)
console.log("Slack ok")
sendMessage(process.env.SLACK_CHANNEL, 'Bonjour !')
})();

bot.message('hello', async ({ message, say }) => {
    await say(`Bonjour <@${message.user}>, que puis-je pour toi?`)
    .catch(console.error)
  });

async function sendMessage (channel, message) {
    await web.chat.postMessage({
        channel: channel,
        text: message,
    })
}
```

But nothing is happening..

My bot.start return in my console "slack ok", when i put a message, my bot sends on my slack channel but when i write hello, it doesn't work.

Someone can explains me why ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like the bot is missing permissions:
As you can read [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/build-a-slackbot-in-node-js-with-slacks-bolt-api/#messagesinslack), the bot needs scope `im:history` to read messages in channels. Have you assigned this scope to the app?

Comment: yes, my scope is : app_home_opened, app_mention, link_shared, message.channels, message.groups, message.im, message. mpim